# How is randomness introduced in java implementation of Quicksort (DualPivotQuicksort)

Tags: java, sorting, big-o, quicksort

I was going through the implementation details of DualPivotQuicksort class in java.

As far as the algorithm is concerned it surely is a variation of the Quicksort, though what doesn't make sense is the way randomness is introduced in the pivot selection and hence to make sure the algorithm runs in **expected** running time of O (n lg (n)).

I referred couple of papers but they more or less explains the algorithm rather than addressing how randomness is dealt for pivot selection or are not very explicit about it:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6602

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say *which* Java implementation so I assume that you are referring to `java.util.DualPivotQuicksort`.

That class doesn't pick a random pivots.  In fact it picks 7 equally spaced candidate pivots from the subarray, sorts them, and uses the 3rd and 5th ones as the (dual) pivots.

Exceptions:

- Small arrays / subarrays are sorted using insertion sort.
- Arrays of `byte` are sorted using either insertion or counting sort.

(Note: this is based on the implementation in Java 7 / 8 )

Comment: How would that method of picking pivots ensure we get an expected O (n lg (n)). Is that only empirical or we have some theoretical proof?

Comment: No, it's only empirical.  There's no proof, and no guarantee of O(n lg n).

Answer (score 1):

The worst case for a simple Quicksort implementation happens when the input is already sorted for your pivot strategy, like if one chooses the pivot as the first element of the sub-array you will get the worst case run time if your elements are already in order.  Because we often are sorting arrays that are "mostly sorted" to begin with by randomizing the pivot selection you can perform much closer to the expected run time in practice.

Ideally you want to pick a pivot that would evenly partition the sub problems, there are several variations of this of which selecting a random element is just one.  Another, another strategy that I have seen samples the array picking 5 elements and then using the median. (**Edit:** From another answer it looks like DualPivotQuicksort is actually this style with 7 sample points then dividing into three partitions.  There is no randomness in this approach, but rather sampling.)

In the end this is all about finding the fastest or most efficient variation for the specific task at hand.  If you have more information about the underlying structure of what you are sorting you can tailor the variation of the algorithm to be more successful on you data sets.  In a library you want to be generally fast but also predictable in the face of "misuse". That is why an approach that has good performance on an already sorted array like this is a good candidate.